# My form submit buttons are not displaying like my a link html buttons

Tags: php, html, css

I have a page here:
http://www.simplypsychics.com/psychicprofile.php?pin=4439

and at the bottom I am using buttons. But my site has a standard button style which I use in the following way:

```
<a href="http://www.simplypsychics.com/readers.html" target="_parent" class="placementtext_button">View all our great psychics</a>
```

The CSS applied to it is this:

```
.placementtext_button {
background-color: #9a3ba8;
background-image:url(headerbuttons2.jpg);
border-radius:5px;
margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
color:#5c5c5a;
font-family:"Century Gothic", sans-serif !important;
font-size:14px !important;
padding:8px !important;
vertical-align: top;
line-height:33px;
text-align:center;
text-decoration:none;
-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
-moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
}
.placementtext_button:hover {
background-color: #494949;
background-image:url(headerbuttons2.jpg);
border-radius:5px;
margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
color:#f8c7ff;
font-family:"Century Gothic", sans-serif !important;
font-size:14px !important;
padding:8px !important;
vertical-align: top;
line-height:33px;
text-align:center;
text-decoration:none;
-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
-moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
}
```

but my PHP buttons look completely different. See this image to explain:

http://i61.tinypic.com/102jck1.jpg

and I tried to modify the CSS to appear the same but it isn't working.

Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

This is the CSS for the button:

```
form input[type="submit"] {
background-color: #9a3ba8;
border-radius: 5px;
margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
color: #5c5c5a;
font-family: "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, 'Muli', sans-serif !important;
font-size: 14px !important;
padding: 8px !important;
vertical-align: top;
line-height: 33px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none !important;
-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
-moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 form input[type="submit"] {
        background-color: #9a3ba8;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
        font-family: "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, 'Muli', sans-serif !important;
        font-size: 14px !important;
        padding: 0px !important;
        vertical-align: top;
        line-height: 33px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none !important;
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
        -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
        letter-spacing: -1px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #ffffff;
        border: none;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks so much guys! I had to change the padding to     padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px !important;
 but other than that, perfecto!

Answer (score 0):

ssergei's on the right track. The key, in this case, is `border: none;`.

This could also all be consolidated a lot more; there's no need to repeat styles that aren't changing during a hover state. And, if possible, it's best to style similarly styled selectors together (separated by commas) to keep your code cleaner and smaller.

```
.placementtext_button,
form input[type="submit"]   {
    background-color: #9a3ba8;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: none;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, 'Muli', sans-serif !important;
    font-size: 14px !important;
    padding: 8px !important;
    vertical-align: top;
    line-height: 33px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
    }

.placementtext_button:hover,
form input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background-color: #494949;
    color:#f8c7ff;
    }
```